# While developing metadata exchange service in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, winforms-to-web

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBus0.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNtZj.jpg)

"Add service reference" is unable to find any service running, which is actually running with the solution "started without debugging".  Also running with another instance of visual studio simultaneously not working.

Comment: Hi, I can't really find a question here. Can you help me out?

Comment: My client code is unable to detect "wcf Service" through "Add service reference" window.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the address

```
http://localhost:9999/mex
```

try the following address

```
http://localhost:9999/ProductService/WCFProductService.svc?singleWsdl
```

Comment: There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:9999/ProductService/WCFProductService.svc/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9999
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:9999/ProductService/WCFProductService.svc'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:9999/ProductService/WCFProductService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

Comment: See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9999
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Comment: I tried the same thing by changing the endpoint address to http://localhost:9999/ProductService/WCFProductService.svc , but of no avail. Appreciate your time though

Comment: Try using "netstat -an" and look for "listening" connections on port 9999. If it's not in the list, your WS is not running.

Comment: Hi Diego, I tried "netstat -an", "netstat -a -o | findstr 9999" as well as checked the url in my browser, service is running. And to my surprise, finally I could see the WCFService in my "Add service reference" in client code. Looks like some inconsistency in behavior. Thanks a lot for your help.